# apoc.periodic.commit doesn't result in updates

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

The following query results in 10 updated nodes:

```
MATCH (a:ns3__Organization)-[r:ns4__isDomiciledIn]->(b:Resource)
WITH a,b LIMIT 10
SET a.isDomiciledIn = b.Country
```

I'm trying to apply it to my whole graph with apoc.periodic.commit through the following query:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.commit("
MATCH (a:ns3__Organization)-[r:ns4__isDomiciledIn]->(b:Resource)
WITH a,b LIMIT $limit
SET a.isDomiciledIn = b.Country
", { limit : 50000});
```

Somehow it results in 0 update. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this one :

```
CALL apoc.periodic.commit("
MATCH (a:ns3__Organization)-[r:ns4__isDomiciledIn]->(b:Resource)
WHERE NOT a.isDomiciledIn = b.Country 
WITH a,b LIMIT $limit
SET a.isDomiciledIn = b.Country
RETURN count(*)
", { limit : 50000});
```

You errors :

- no `count(*)` at the end of your query. SO your query never ends
- no `WHERE` clause to filter the result to only nodes that are not yet updated

Comment: Thanks Benoit ! For some reason this query hangs and the database is not updated. Do you know what's going on?

Comment: By looking at the code,  if you don't have a result (or a Numeroc result), the count is `0`. So your query is doing only one loop.

Comment: for reference : https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/3.4/src/main/java/apoc/periodic/Periodic.java#L120-L133